# Help identifying a small flowering plant

Tags: wildflowers

[image: small unknown plant]

This little guy started popping up around my house. We never planted it, but I'd love to know what we have growing here. It is small type, the  flowers have a honeysuckle  type style,  5 petals and the leaves of the plant itself are shiny , slightly like purselane. It is growing in Florida. 
TYIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't get an answer here, Dave's Garden Blog is a go to for me. I think it's Coral Creeper.
https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/57323/